# Código PHP abre no navegador

Tags: php, apache

Não estou conseguindo realizar a instalação do PHP na minha máquina.
Quando executo uma página no navegador, ele retorna o código escrito no .php.

Instalei o Apache 2.2.9 e o PHP 5.2.1, e realizei todas as mudanças baseada por [este tutorial](http://www.hardware.com.br/tutoriais/apache-php-mysql-windows/instalando-apache.html)

Mesmo com todas as mudanças, ele continua com o mesmo erro.
O Apache funciona normalmente, quando chamo localhost, ele me retorna: Its Works, porém o PHP que não consegue executar.

Uso o sistema operacional Windows 7 Home Basic 86x.

Comment: Pode estar faltando o FastCGI. Tente configurar seguindo este tutorial http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/install.windows.iis7.php, mas esta versão do PHP é muito antiga, tente instalar uma solução completa como o WAMP http://wampserver.com/en, já com uma versão mais recente do PHP.

Comment: no seu mesmo tutorial, tente fazer a configuração descrita [aqui](http://www.hardware.com.br/tutoriais/apache-php-mysql-windows/configurando-php-manualmente.html)

Comment: Eu já instalei o Wamp, possuía ele no PC e mesmo assim dá o erro. EasyPhp também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se ele esta mostrando o código escrito no arquivo .php é possivel que:

1. Você não tenha colocado o projeto dentro de uma pasta especifica onde fica acessivel ao localhost.
2. tenha colocado neste local accessivel ao localhost mas esta acessando sua pagina .php usando o protocolo file:\.
3. Utilize um Xampp, Wamp ou easyphp para instalar e configurar tudo de forma automática para você, no caso destas soluções a unica coisa que você deveria fazer é colocar o projeto dentro da pasta raiz do localhost (htdocs por exemplo) e chamar no browser com localhost.

Comment: Ele estava na pasta htdocs mesmo, e mesmo assim ele aparece o código.

Eu coloco o código: "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" (sem aspas), dentro da pasta e executo, e o mesmo aparece no navegador, e não executa a função.

Já instalei o Wamp e o EasyPhp e mesmo assim continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: acessou pelo localhost?

Comment: Agora está funcionando, quando eu puxo pelo navegador, colocando: "localhost/exemplo.php", mas se eu executar da própria pasta, dando clique duplo pra abrir no navegador, ele exibe o código. E quando eu coloco um formulário em html, e mando fazer uma ação em php (link externo), também exibe o código, independente de eu colocar: envio.php ou localhost/envio.php

Comment: sim quando vc dá um duplo click vc abre a pagina com o protocolo `file:\\\` pelo browser isso não executa o php, com localhost você executa usando o protocolo `http` e executa o php como tinha dito.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado.

Isso eu tenho como alterar?

Comment: Dar duplo clique na .php e já ir executando como java não há como mudar, sinalize que minha resposta lhe foi util marcando a seta verde ao lado e de um upvote (triangulo com ponta para cima)

Comment: O clique duplo não funciona porque o PHP, diferente do HTML, precisa ser interpretado antes de ser executado. Ele roda do lado do servidor, ou seja, utilizando o Wamp, é criado um servidor local em seu computador. Caso você teste seu arquivo em outro computador que não tenha um servidor local com o PHP instalado, irá acontecer o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 5):

Ao ler a sua pergunta, me lembrei de uma resposta minha no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214808/why-is-photo-not-displayed-using-img/27215057#27215057), acredito que seja este o caminho:

O problema é que talvez você tenha acessado a página pelo protocolo FILE ao invés do protocolo HTTP, como já dito pelo Gustavo e pelo Ricardo, vou explicar a diferenças:

### Diferenças entre HTTP e FILE

1. Você deve aprender as diferenças entre "protocolo http" e "protocolo de arquivo".

   **Protocolo HTTP:**

   Funções HTTP como um protocolo de solicitação-resposta no modelo de computação cliente-servidor. Um navegador da Web, por exemplo, pode ser o cliente e um aplicativo em execução em um computador que hospeda um web site pode ser o servidor. O cliente envia uma mensagem de solicitação HTTP para o servidor. O servidor, que fornece recursos, como arquivos HTML e outros conteúdos, ou exercer outras funções em nome do cliente, retorna uma mensagem de resposta para o cliente. A resposta contém informações status de conclusão sobre o pedido e pode também conter conteúdo solicitado em seu corpo da mensagem.

   **Protocolo File:**

   O esquema URI arquivo é um esquema de URI especificado em "RFC 1630" e "RFC 1738", normalmente usado para recuperar arquivos de dentro de seu próprio computador, se abrir um arquivo PHP diretamente o URL na barra de endereço geralmente irá apresentar isto:

[image: protocol file Opera browser]

2. Em segundo lugar, a sua necessidade aprender sobre "developer tools" (aba de rede/network tab), com o developer tools você pode detectar "caminho", cabeçalhos e respostas de página para entender problemas específicos.

   **Usando developer tools no Chrome (em alguns navegadores que usam Webkit é similar):** https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance

   Exemplo:
   [image: network chrome]
   <sub>(fonte: [chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/images/network-panel.png))</sub>

   **Usando Firefox:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

   Exemplo:
   [image: network firefox]

   **Usando Safari 8**: https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/

   [image: Safari 8 network tools]

Ferramentas que recomendo para instalar PHP na sua máquina:

- http://www.wampserver.com/en/ (windows, apache, php, mysql)
- https://www.apachefriends.org/ (cross-platform, apache, php, mysql,
  pearl)

Answer (score -2):

Se você estiver acessando via:
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/   o problema é este.
Acesse apenas por: localhost/pasta_do_seu_projeto_no_XAMPP

Espero ter ajudado