# Formulário não envia dados

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando fazer com que os dados digitados pelo usuário apareçam em outra página quando ele clicar no botão só que a página é atualizada mas não contem as informações digitadas.

Arquivo HTML

```
 <form action="php/dados.php" method="post">

        <input type="text" id="cNome" name="tNome" size="20" maxlength="20" placeholder="       Digite Seu Nome"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Cancelar"/>
  </form>
```

Arquivo PHP

```
<?php

    $nome = $_POST["tNome"];
    echo "Obrigado $nome";
?>
```

Já olhei várias vezes mas não consigo achar o erro,qual seria?

Comment: Não use stacksnippets (trecho de código) sem necessidade, eles não são pra formatar e sim pra executar códigos js+css+html que façam alguma coisa, se não for pra fazer nada use a **marcação normal.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve estar usando ou protocolo `file:///` ao invés de `http://` (por exemplo acessou `file:///c:/Users/Lone/Documents/projeto/form.php` ao invés de `http://localhost/form.php`) ou você deve estar usando Apache sem PHP.

Como expliquei aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/62797/3635, se for Windows instale ou [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html) ou [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) ou [easyphp](http://www.easyphp.org)

Se já tiver instalado é porque talvez esteja acessando algo assim pelo navegador `file:///c:/wamp/www/form.php`, veja se a URL no navegador **"parecido"** com isto:

[image: url navegador]

Isso não vai funcionar, o protocolo file é para rodar arquivos locais, o Apache é um servidor, mesmo que local e você precisa rodar por ele.

Depois de instalar o Xampp, Lamp (linux), Wamp, Mamp (Mac OSX), você deve copiar teus arquivos para as seguintes "possíveis" pastas (estas pastas são de exemplo, mas o caminho deve ser parecido):

- Windows e Wamp: `c:/wamp/www`
- Windows e Xampp: `c:/xampp/htdocs`
- Linux e Lamp/Xampp: `/otp/lamp/htdocs`
- Linux instalado via repositório: `/var/www`

Claro que é possível apontar outras pastas, mas isto é outra história.

Comment: Então no caso se eu precisar mostrar esse arquivo para alguém sem deixar online não vai ser possível ?

Comment: @LoneTonberry se não estiver "online" não tem como a pessoa ver, afinal online é online né? Agora Xampp, Wamp, `http://localhost`, etc não tem nada haver com "online", eles rodam só na tua maquina e isso é usado para você desenvolver suas páginas e scripts. **Agora** se você quer exibir remotamente para alguém a página você pode colocar em uma hospedagem (deve ser o online que se refere) ou tentar usar no-ip, isso deve ajudar: [**acesso externo com wamp**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50934/3635)

Comment: Quis dizer que eu vou precisar levar esse trabalho para outra máquina, mas não quero deixar o site online.Então no caso eu teria que ter instalado naquela máquina esses programas também ou não ?

Comment: @LoneTonberry isso mesmo, tem que ter instalado, por isso chamamos de ambiente de desenvolvimento, não tem como criar um script PHP sem ter o programa PHP (vem junto com Xampp ou Wamp, ou outros, só precisa de um deles), também não tem como rodar um script PHP para servidor HTTP sem ter um servidor HTTP na maquina. O Xampp e outros tem o Apache (servidor) e o PHP (interpretador), basta instalar, se não tiver eles seria o mesmo que querer editar um arquivo do MSWord (.doc e .docx) sem ter o Office 2007 ou Office 365 instalado.

Comment: Então quer dizer que o correto seria eu pegar todos os meus arquivos de HTML, JS, CSS , PHP  e jogar ele dentro das respectivas pastas dos programas ?

Comment: @LoneTonberry sim scripts php só rodam se tiver o programa PHP e o Apache precisa de uma pasta padrão. Arquivos .php são criados para rodar em sites e esses sites usam um servidor, como Apache, Nginx, Lighttpd, etc. Esses servidores tem que ter uma pasta aonde está aonde ficariam os dados que vão para o site, como eu disse arquivos .php precisam do programa php.exe, não ter ele é como tentar editar um .doc sem ter o Office, recomendo que leia isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115690/3635

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52504/discussion-between-lone-tonberry-and-guilherme-nascimento).