# upload arquivos mutiplos

Tags: php, jquery

Como faço para pegar os arquivos no *AJAX*?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o *AJAX* que esta funcionando, porem não estou passando como data os arquivos, estou pegando no *PHP*

```
$('#btnenviarpdf').click(function () {

        var id = $('#modalADDPDF').data('id');  

        $.post('estrutura/upaddpdf.php',{acao:'inserir',id:id},function(r) { 

           var m = jQuery.parseJSON(r);        
           if (m.success) {


            $('#modalADDPDF').modal('hide');
            toastr["success"](m.msg);           
            $("#listapdf").load(location.href + " #listapdf>*", "");    

           } else {

            toastr["error"](m.msg);
            $('#modalADDPDF').modal('hide');

           }             
        });
    });
```

Ocorre esse erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: img in upaddpdf.php on line *14*

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    include("../includes/config.php");

    if($_POST){

        $data = array('success' => '0',
                  'msg' => 'Ocorreu um erro, nada foi inserido!');

        $acao   = $_POST['acao'];
        $id     = $_POST['id'];

        IF($acao != ""){
            //INFO IMAGEM
            $file       = $_FILES['img'];  <<<=== linha 14
            $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

            //PASTA
            $folder     = 'arquivos/anexos';
```

Agora fiz desta forma, mas continua o mesmo problema.

JQUERY

```
$('#btnenviarpdf').click(function () {

    var id = $('#modalADDPDF').data('id');  

    var form_data = new FormData();
    var ins = document.getElementById('multiFiles').files.length;
    for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
        form_data.append("files[]", document.getElementById('multiFiles').files[x]);
    }

    $.post('estrutura/upaddpdf.php',{acao:'inserir',id:id},function(r) { 

       var m = jQuery.parseJSON(r);        
       if (m.success) {


        $('#modalADDPDF').modal('hide');
        toastr["success"](m.msg);           
        $("#listapdf").load(location.href + " #listapdf>*", "");    

       } else {

        toastr["error"](m.msg);
        $('#modalADDPDF').modal('hide');

       }             
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
include("../includes/config.php");

if($_POST){

    $data = array('success' => '0',
              'msg' => 'Ocorreu um erro, nada foi inserido!');

    $acao   = $_POST['acao'];
    $id     = $_POST['id'];

    IF($acao != ""){
        //INFO IMAGEM
        $file       = $_FILES['files'];
        $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));
```

Formulário:

```
<form id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="acaopdf" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id?>">
                        <div class="file-field">                    

                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-sm">
                                    <span id="spa">Escolha o arquivo</span>                                         
                                    <input type="file" id="mulitplefileuploader" name="img[]" multiple>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        <center><input class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-sm" id="btnenviarpdf" type="submit" value="Enviar" /></center>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

Comment: Já tentou dar um var_dump ou print_r na variável $_FILE, qual foi o retorno? Ou então tenta inspecionar a requisição e veja se os arquivos estão sendo enviados.

Comment: ja fiz isso, dia que a variável não foi definida..

Comment: Desfiz a edição porque ela descaracteriza a resposta existente e não dá detalhes de qual era o erro, por favor faça da maneira que falei, diga qual erro ocorreu usando o console do navegador e olhando na aba network (se o seu navegador estiver em português o nome da aba é "Rede"), se não souber como fazer veja esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/62797/3635

Comment: valeu pela ajuda, mas nada acontece, pode ser meu formulario

Answer (score 0):

Teu Ajax não faz nada além de enviar `{acao:'inserir',id:id}`, ou seja não tem como o PHP receber o upload já que você não enviou nada, para enviar os arquivos é necessário passar o `FormData` no campo data e setar o `processData` como `false`

Será necessário passar o acao e o id no proprio `FormData`:

```
//O mesmo que acao: 'inserir'
form_data.append("acao", "inserir");

//O mesmo que id: id
form_data.append("id", id);
```

> Não é necessário JSON.parse, pode simplesmente usar `dataType: "json"`

Outra coisa interessante a se usar é o `.fail`, pois pode ocorrer erros no servidor ou até mesmo na internet do usuário, com o fail você irá poder informar se algo falhou nesta situação:

```
.fail(function (xhr, textErr) {
    toastr["error"](textErr);
    $('#modalADDPDF').modal('hide');
});
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
var id = $('#modalADDPDF').data('id');  

var form_data = new FormData();
var ins = document.getElementById('multiFiles').files.length;

for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
    form_data.append("files[]", document.getElementById('multiFiles').files[x]);
}

//O mesmo que acao: 'inserir'
form_data.append("acao", "inserir");

//O mesmo que id: id
form_data.append("id", id);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'estrutura/upaddpdf.php',
  data: form_data, //Passa o forma data
  dataType: "json",//Força o tipo json na resposta
  processData: false // <--- false
}).done(function(r) {
   if (m.success) {


    $('#modalADDPDF').modal('hide');
    toastr["success"](m.msg);           
    $("#listapdf").load(location.href + " #listapdf>*", "");    

   } else {

    toastr["error"](m.msg);
    $('#modalADDPDF').modal('hide');

   }     
}).fail(function (xhr, textErr) {
    toastr["error"](textErr);
    $('#modalADDPDF').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Eu tava editando as duplicatas... Tem vários posts sobre File + Ajax + PHP - Mas como vc reabriu e respondeu, vou deixar a seu critério.

Comment: @Bacco sim, inclusive uma minha de 2015 que explica bem isto, só que tem um detalhe que difere, o campo `acao:` e o campo `id`, não são campos do form e nem tem explicação na outra resposta, desculpe meio que passar por cima, mas é que eu já estava na metade da resposta.

Comment: Tem postagens com e sem form, e com explicação. O fechamento pela primeira que eu achei foi só pra evitar alguém postar duplicata mesmo. Mas conforme comentei, fica a seu critério, não posso dar muita atenção pra isso agora, de qq forma. Talvez não tenha nenhuma "completa".

Comment: nao tem jeito, vou para o refresch da tela mesmo, não consigo fazer funcionar..

Comment: @JeffersonMeireles era erro meu, faltou corrigir o nome da var, o correto é `$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'estrutura/upaddpdf.php',
  data: form_data,
  dataType: "json",
  processData: false
})`, acabei de editar a resposta, dá uma olhada.

Comment: nada, vou editar minha pergunta e por todos os arquivos, devo esta errando em alguma coisa

Comment: @JeffersonMeireles como assim nada? Qual erro aparece na aba network no console (F12)? Ainda é o erro de variavel não definida?