# comunicação MySQL, PHP e HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Boa noite pessoal, eu ja havia falado sobre isso, mas parece que não estão entendendo o que eu quero dizer, então vou ver se explico melhor:
até onde sei, fiz tudo certo, no meu caso estou usando o XAMP,
ou seja, a maior parte é configurada automaticamente, mesmo assim, no fim, ao tentar executar ele não me traz o resultado esperado, ele me traz no html, no browser, um erro de comunicação mysql, vou passar meus scripts:

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
`nome` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`sexo` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`ddd` INT( 2 ) ,
`telefone` INT( 8 ) ,
`endereço` VARCHAR( 70 ) NOT NULL ,
`cidade` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`estado` VARCHAR( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
`bairro` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`país` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`login` VARCHAR( 12 ) NOT NULL ,
`senha` VARCHAR( 12 ) NOT NULL ,
`news` VARCHAR( 8 ) ,
`id` INT( 200 ) AUTO_INCREMENT ,
UNIQUE (
`id` 
)
);
```

SCRIPT PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
// RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !
$nome   = $_POST ["nome"];  //atribuição do campo "nome" vindo do formulário para variavel  
$email  = $_POST ["email"]; //atribuição do campo "email" vindo do formulário para variavel
$ddd    = $_POST ["ddd"];   //atribuição do campo "ddd" vindo do formulário para variavel
$tel    = $_POST ["telefone"];  //atribuição do campo "telefone" vindo do formulário para variavel
$endereco   = $_POST ["endereco"];  //atribuição do campo "endereco" vindo do formulário para variavel
$cidade = $_POST ["cidade"];    //atribuição do campo "cidade" vindo do formulário para variavel
$estado = $_POST ["estado"];    //atribuição do campo "estado" vindo do formulário para variavel
$bairro = $_POST ["bairro"];    //atribuição do campo "bairro" vindo do formulário para variavel
$pais   = $_POST ["pais"];  //atribuição do campo "pais" vindo do formulário para variavel
$login  = $_POST ["login"]; //atribuição do campo "login" vindo do formulário para variavel
$senha  = $_POST ["senha"]; //atribuição do campo "senha" vindo do formulário para variavel
$news   = $_POST ["news"];  //atribuição do campo "news" vindo do formulário para variavel
$sexo   = $_POST ["sexo"];  //atribuição do campo "sexo" vindo do formulário para variavel
//Gravando no banco de dados !

//conectando com o localhost - mysql
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$conexao)
    die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
//conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
$banco = mysql_select_db("clientes",$conexao);
if (!$banco)
    die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());



$query = "INSERT INTO `clientes` ( `nome` , `email` , `sexo` , `ddd` , `telefone` , `endereço` , `cidade` , `estado` , `bairro` , `país` , `login` , `senha` , `news` , `id` ) 
VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$sexo', '$ddd', '$tel', '$endereco', '$cidade', '$estado', '$bairro', '$pais', '$login', '$senha', '$news', '')";

mysql_query($query,$conexao);

echo "Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!<br>Agradecemos a atenção.";
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>CADASTRO DE CLIENTES COM BANCO DE DADOS E PHP</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    color: #FF0000;
    font-size: x-small;
}
.style3 {color: #0000FF; font-size: x-small; }
-->
</style>
<!--
                        ##########  Créditos  ##########
                        #                                   #
                        #   Autor: Rodrigo Ramos e Taitsonn #
                        #                                   #
                        #   Nome do script:FormularioCliente#
                        #   Bonus: validaCampo              #
                        #                                   #
                        #                                   #
                        #####################################

-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function validaCampo()
{
if(document.cadastro.nome.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo nome é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.cadastro.email.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo email é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.cadastro.endereco.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo endereço é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.cadastro.cidade.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo Cidade é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.cadastro.estado.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo Estado é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.cadastro.bairro.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo Bairro é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.cadastro.pais.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo país é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else
    if(document.cadastro.login.value=="")
    {
    alert("O Campo Login é obrigatório!");
    return false;
    }
else    
if(document.cadastro.senha.value=="")
    {
    alert("Digite uma senha!");
    return false;
    }
else
return true;
}
<!-- Fim do JavaScript que validará os campos obrigatórios! -->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" action="cadastro.php" onsubmit="return validaCampo(); return false;">
  <table width="625" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="69">Nome:</td>
      <td width="546"><input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" size="70" maxlength="60" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="70" maxlength="60" />
      <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sexo:</td>
      <td><input name="sexo" type="radio" value="Masculino" checked="checked" />
        Masculino 
        <input name="sexo" type="radio" value="Feminino" />
        Feminino <span class="style1">*</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DDD:</td>
      <td><input name="ddd" type="text" id="ddd" size="4" maxlength="2" />
      Telefone:
        <input name="telefone" type="text" id="telefone" />
        <span class="style3">Apenas n&uacute;meros</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Endere&ccedil;o:</td>
      <td><input name="endereco" type="text" id="endereco" size="70" maxlength="70" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cidade:</td>
      <td><input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" maxlength="20" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Estado:</td>
      <td><select name="estado" id="estado">
        <option>Selecione...</option>
        <option value="AC">AC</option>
        <option value="AL">AL</option>
        <option value="AP">AP</option>
        <option value="AM">AM</option>
        <option value="BA">BA</option>
        <option value="CE">CE</option>
        <option value="ES">ES</option>
        <option value="DF">DF</option>
        <option value="MA">MA</option>
        <option value="MT">MT</option>
        <option value="MS">MS</option>
        <option value="MG">MG</option>
        <option value="PA">PA</option>
        <option value="PB">PB</option>
        <option value="PR">PR</option>
        <option value="PE">PE</option>
        <option value="PI">PI</option>
        <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
        <option value="RN">RN</option>
        <option value="RS">RS</option>
        <option value="RO">RO</option>
        <option value="RR">RR</option>
        <option value="SC">SC</option>
        <option value="SP">SP</option>
        <option value="SE">SE</option>
        <option value="TO">TO</option>
          </select>
        <span class="style1">*      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bairro:</td>
      <td><input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" maxlength="20" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pa&iacute;s:</td>
      <td><input name="pais" type="text" id="pais" maxlength="20" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Login:</td>
      <td><input name="login" type="text" id="login" maxlength="12" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Senha:</td>
      <td><input name="senha" type="password" id="senha" maxlength="12" />
          <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input name="news" type="checkbox" id="news" value="ATIVO" checked="checked" />
Desejo receber novidades e informa&ccedil;&otilde;es sobre o conte&uacute;do deste site. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><p>
        <input name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="Concluir meu Cadastro!" /> 
        <br />
          <input name="limpar" type="reset" id="limpar" value="Limpar Campos preenchidos!" />
          <br />
          <span class="style1">* Campos com * s&atilde;o obrigat&oacute;rios!          </span></p>
      <p>&nbsp; </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

tento gravar e no browser aparece apenas isso:

> ".mysql_error()); //conectando com a tabela do banco de dados $banco = mysql_select_db("clientes",$conexao); if (!$banco) die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error()); $query = "INSERT INTO `clientes` ( `nome` , `email` , `sexo` , `ddd` , `telefone` , `endereço` , `cidade` , `estado` , `bairro` , `país` , `login` , `senha` , `news` , `id` ) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$sexo', '$ddd', '$tel', '$endereco', '$cidade', '$estado', '$bairro', '$pais', '$login', '$senha', '$news', '')"; mysql_query($query,$conexao); echo "Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!
>   Agradecemos a atenção."; ?>

Comment: O nome do banco é igual ao nome da tabela?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62722/c%C3%B3digo-php-abre-no-navegador

Comment: O nome da sua base de dados tem é `clientes`?

Comment: Só pra lembrar, as funções `mysql_` estão obsoletas e foram retiradas na versão 7 do php

Answer (score 0):

Procure organizar seu código melhor, e sempre que possível separar o **HTML** do **PHP**.

Seu problema pelo que deu pra entender está focado na conexão com o banco de dados, sugiro fazer as seguintes melhorias no seu código e testar:

SCRIPT PHP (salve como script.php):

```
<?php 
    // RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !
    $nome   = $_POST ["nome"];  //atribuição do campo "nome" vindo do formulário para variavel  
    $email  = $_POST ["email"]; //atribuição do campo "email" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $ddd    = $_POST ["ddd"];   //atribuição do campo "ddd" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $tel    = $_POST ["telefone"];  //atribuição do campo "telefone" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $endereco   = $_POST ["endereco"];  //atribuição do campo "endereco" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $cidade = $_POST ["cidade"];    //atribuição do campo "cidade" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $estado = $_POST ["estado"];    //atribuição do campo "estado" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $bairro = $_POST ["bairro"];    //atribuição do campo "bairro" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $pais   = $_POST ["pais"];  //atribuição do campo "pais" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $login  = $_POST ["login"]; //atribuição do campo "login" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $senha  = $_POST ["senha"]; //atribuição do campo "senha" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $news   = $_POST ["news"];  //atribuição do campo "news" vindo do formulário para variavel
    $sexo   = $_POST ["sexo"];  //atribuição do campo "sexo" vindo do formulário para variavel

    //conectando com o localhost - mysql
    $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    if(!$conexao) {
        die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> " . mysql_error());
    } else {
        //conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
        $banco = mysql_select_db("clientes", $conexao);
        if (!$banco) {
            die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
        } else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO `clientes` ( `nome` , `email` , `sexo` , `ddd` , `telefone` , `endereço` , `cidade` , `estado` , `bairro` , `país` , `login` , `senha` , `news` , `id` ) 
    VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$sexo', '$ddd', '$tel', '$endereco', '$cidade', '$estado', '$bairro', '$pais', '$login', '$senha', '$news', '')";

            mysql_query($query, $conexao);

            echo "Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!<br>Agradecemos a atenção.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Modificações:

- Informar que a senha de conexão é branca, para o usuário root (apenas precaução).
- Nas condições `if`, usar as chaves `{}` e a condicional `else`, para determinar o que acontece em cada situação. Sim a função `die()`, encerra a execução do script após informar uma mensagem, mas não parece ser isso que está incorreto.

HTML do SCRIPT (salve como index.php ou o nome que desejar para receber a requisição):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    include_once("script.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Isso talvez não resolva seu problema, mas com certeza irá ajudá-lo a enxergar melhor o que está ocorrendo. Informe se resolve.